# Different create file permissions for different commands

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

Trying to create file in `/opt` folder with command:

```
sudo echo '01' > aaa
```

Got error `-bash: aaa: Permission denied`

Works fine if I create file, edit and save with vim

```
sudo vim aaa
```

Why I'm getting error while create file with one command while no error with other one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell performs the redirection *as you* **before** sudo starts. You want:

```sh
sudo sh -c 'echo "01" > aaa'
```

so that the "aaa" file is created in the sudo process.